# Ionic and wordpress integration with subdomain

Tags: wordpress, ionic-framework

I need help. I have wordpress installed both on my domain and subdomain.

I try to integrate wordpress posts in my ionic app using this tutorial:
https://devdactic.com/ionic-4-wordpress-client/

This work on my domain but not on my subdomain.

What i really want is to my ionic app get posts from wordpress installed on my subdomain.

Answer (score 0):

The first think, you have to do it's very if you have access to this: http://yoursubdomain/wp-json/wp/v2/.

If you don't have any access to this, you have to change your wordpress permalinks, And put  Post name as permalinks structure inside wordpress settings, don't forget to save.

If that doesn't solve your issue, explains the error that you have.

Comment: Thank you for the reply @frankho-kevinho.

I already change my permalink structure to the post name. I can view my wordpress json. Here is my subdomain url http://inanam.pcsmalaysia.org/wp-json/wp/v2/

Comment: Your are welcome dont forget to mark this question as the correct answer :)